# How can I initialize an empty variable for LINQ join result?

Tags: c#, linq, scope

I have a LINQ query and I need to initialize it's variable before the execution, at the top of the razor page. As you see the variable q initializes in different scope than where it will be used later.

```
if(state)
{
var q = 
   from table1 in connection.Get<DbTable1> ...
   join table2 in connection.Get<DbTable2> ...
   ...;
 }
 ...lines...
 ...lines...
 if(state)
 {
     foreach(var item in q)
     {
     ...
     }
 }
```

So how can I declare the var q at the top of the code to enlarge it's scope and cover the entire code? In short how can I define & initialize q just before the first if.

Comment: When you hover on "var" q, you will see the type of q. By that you can initialize it at top.

Comment: {Composite.Data.Caching.CachingQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType4<System.Guid, string, <>f__AnonymousType0<Alicilar>, string, string>>}

Comment: Why can't you initialize it just before you use it?

Comment: I don't know datatype and var q = null; won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution in general, especially if projecting anonymous types.  The only potential workaround I can think of is to use `Lazy<T>` and compiler type inference capabilities like this.

First, a small helper method

```
static Lazy<T> Lazy<T>(Func<T> factory) { return new Lazy<T>(factory, true); }
```

and then

```
var q = Lazy(() =>
    from table1 in connection.Get<DbTable1> ...
    join table2 in connection.Get<DbTable2> ...
    ...);
if (state)
{
}
...lines...
...lines...
if (state)
{
    foreach(var item in q.Value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, if LINQ uses lazy evaluation, I could declare the q outside of the if block since it wont be executed till I use it. Right?

Comment: @NimeCloud It does for execution, but not for building the query, which could have a side effects - like running a db migration etc. That's why it's better the way I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need for declaring the type that your query returns. You can just use the `var` keyword in your `foreach`.

```
foreach(var item in q)
{
    // ...
}
```

When your code will be compiled both the type of `q` and `item` would be inferred from your code, without having to state them explicitly.

However, if you still want to declare them explicitly, you have to do something like below:

```
IEnumerable<ClassName> = from table1 in connection.Get<DbTable1>
                         join table2 in connection.Get<DbTable2>
                         on table1.A equals table2.A
                         select new ClassName
                         {
                             // Set the values for your properties here
                         };
```

where `ClassName` is a class that represents the type of objects you want to select from the join of these tables.

Comment: Compiler doesn't compile that code because of undefined variable q in foreach loop. Notice the if(state) scope.

Comment: So we don't you declare the query outside the `if` state? and then consume it in your foreach statement, as you already does checking the value of `state`? Furthermore, I don't see the reason why you have two separate if statements with the same condition? Shouldn't you have only one?

Comment: @christos : Because the razor page is tooo long.

Comment: @NimeCloud as a general rule, it would better you avoid making data related actions in your views. A view is responsible only fro showing some data. That being said, I suggest you do this task in another layer and let the controller pass the data to the view through a model.

Comment: It's not MVC, just old school c# + html razor code in Composite C1 CMS.

Comment: Ok, then I think that using the second option, it address your problem. Correct?